# Set div style to avoid control displacement

Tags: css, asp.net

I have three divs which i set `float:left` side by side.
In all these three divs,  i have one `textbox`, one `checkbox` and one `button`. I have set `checkbox` set to `visible = false` initially. On click of `button` i am setting the `checkbox` visibility to true. by doing this div position gets adjust to left and causing layout problem. How can i set div style to  avoid this layout displacement problem.I want there should not be any control displacement while show and hiding the `checkbox` I am newbie in css.

Here is my fiddle link [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lppme028/6/)

Comment: Nice one, where do you want that button to get set. ?

Comment: I want there should be space already between second and third div to adjust the checkbox space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the css property `visibility`? The `visibility` attribute allows the element to be hidden, but leaves the space where it would have been. For more information about it, read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Lppme028/22/

**CSS**

```
#txt
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#btn").click(function (){
        $("#txt").visibilityToggle();
    }) 
}); 

jQuery.fn.visibilityToggle = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', function(i, visibility) {
        return (visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    });
};
```

Comment: Can u please post me some example. I am newbie in css

Comment: not working. still causing control to displace from its position

Comment: There you go. Check the demo out. Should be working.

Comment: @RajeevKumar: I think pwee167 has cracked it for you.. :)